# Use ssl server with mqttkit in ios

Tags: ios, iphone, ssl, mqtt

I am using MQTTKit for chat in my iPhone application.Can anyone help me in making connection of MQTTKit with ssl server.

I am using library from https://github.com/jmesnil/MQTTKit

It works fine but the problem is i want to use ssl server.

I am using following method :-

```
mosquitto_username_pw_set(mosq, cstrUsername, cstrPassword);

mosquitto_reconnect_delay_set(mosq, self.reconnectDelay, self.reconnectDelayMax, self.reconnectExponentialBackoff);

if (mosquitto_tls_set(mosq, [caFile cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding], NULL, [clientFile cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding], [clientKeyFile cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding], NULL)) {
    NSLog(@"error setting up TLS");
}

mosquitto_connect(mosq, cstrHost, self.port, self.keepAlive);

dispatch_async(self.queue, ^{
    LogDebug(@"start mosquitto loop on %@", self.queue);
    mosquitto_loop_forever(mosq, -1, 1);
    LogDebug(@"end mosquitto loop on %@", self.queue);
});
```

The method 'mosquitto_tls_set' always return error. Can anyone please help me to reslove this problem as i have stuck in it from last week.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @chriz: please **stop** *`abusing`* *formatting* when **`it`** is `completely` ***unnecessary***!

Comment: Qantas94Heavy, what is wrong in this question. Please let me know if anything is unnecessary in this question as i found a lot and not get a answer from anywhere regarding MQTT server connection.

Comment: Qantas 94 Heavy, Please let me know if you understand my question or you need any other information regarding it. you can check whole code from github link.

Comment: Sorry, I was referring to someone else who had edited your question to make it look worse than before.

Comment: What is the error you get from mosquitto_tls_set?

Comment: I am getting 'MOSQ_ERR_NOT_SUPPORTED' error. because the TLS_support branch could not be compiled correctly, cause the WITH_TLS not defined.

Comment: mosquitto_tls_set keeps returning MOSQ_ERR_NOT_SUPPORTED because WITH_TLS is not defined. How can I set this ?